# In Python, how to discard an argument in a printf-style format string?

Tags: python, string-interpolation

Sometimes you are given the opportunity to customize a printf-style format string which is used to output something. You have no control, however, on how it is used. Your format string *must* include as many placeholders as the number of values the `%` operator is used with. Otherwise, you get a TypeError: “not all arguments converted during string formatting”.

Then, **how to discard a value?** From reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting), there is apparently no conversion type specifically for that.

For instance, let’s say I use the library function defined below, but I am not interested in the number 42 and just want to print “Hello world”.

```py
def some_library_function(fmt):
    print(fmt % 42)
```

Comment: Why are you using a function that outputs 42 if you don't want 42 to be output?

Comment: Of course this is a minimal example… In a more realistic setting you may use a function / library / program which does more interesting things, and which happens to print things (but is not a mere proxy to `print`!), and you want to customize what is printed.

Comment: How does that work if, again, you do not control the code that performs interpolation?

Comment: “Artificial restriction“ how so! Not being in control of the API/interface/call-it-however-you-like of libraries/software you rely on is, I believe, a fairly typical situation? But if you want a specific (irrelevant to the general question) example: [the footnotes extension to Python-Markdown](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/footnotes/) adds supports for footnotes in a Markdown parser. It inserts backlinks whose text, by default, is `Jump back to footnote %d in the text.` You can change this text, but as you can see, it is a printf-style format, and it expects one integer value.

Comment: Anyway, I don’t see the point in challenging the *why* if not for providing an helpful answer to the *how*.

Comment: Of course, I agree that, If I had written the code myself, I would have done it differently.
“They accept pull requests” Indeed: figuring out the internal code of the software, writing a patch with extra bureaucracy (writing unit tests, maintaining a changelog and stuff), submitting a PR with breaking changes, hoping that someone considers it, accepts it and merges it in reasonable time, and waiting that it reaches release, is obviously simpler and faster than writing `%.0s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `%.0s`**.

```py
some_library_function('Hello world%.0s')
# prints: 'Hello world'
```

Explanation: `.0` specifies a *precision* of zero, which for `s`trings is interpreted as the maximal number of characters to include in the result. So the value passed to `%` is converted to a string using `str()`, then this string is truncated to length zero.

Comment: If you had included this example in your question, it would have made your question much clearer.

Comment: I… did? -------